# Insert data to master detail tables by a stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

I'm trying to add data to my master/detail table by using a stored procedure.

I tried this:

```
private void ekle()
{ 
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("invinputfrompo", bag);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?trnotes", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = tb1.Text;
    for (int i = 0; i <= dg1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dg1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.Add("?docno", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dg1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?idpodetails", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dg1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?idmat", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(dg1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?sn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dg1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?qty", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(dg1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
            //if (dg1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "") { cmd.Parameters.Add("?shelflife", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value; }
            //else { cmd.Parameters.Add("?shelflife", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = dg1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); }
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?shelflife", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dg1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
        }
    }
    cmd.Connection = bag;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Only the first parameter "trnotes" will be added to the master table, other parameters will be added to the detail table.

I made loop like this but the way is not successful. it says you already defined "docno" (the first parameter in detail table)

Could you help for the data entry?

Answer (score 0):

When your if statement runs for the second time, it tries to add `docno` to the list of parameters that was created on the first iteration. As `docno` was added in that first iteration, it already exists.

There are a couple of ways you could get around this:

- Execute your stored procedure for each row. The downside is that you
  have the overhead of additional DB calls.
- Use [User-Defined Table Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx). You would build up your table in C#
  and then pass that as a parameter to your stored procedure to
  insert into your table.